# Mac C# app to open Word templates, insert text from app form/window texboxes to .docx text fields and save them

Tags: c#, macos, templates, text, ms-word

I have a job related aim to create a app, which comes as a program window with text fields, on button click opens a Word file template, inserts text from textboxes to .docx text fields and saves the file on the disc. I have some exp with Windows.Forms C#, where I've successfully made a program executing these exact commands. Works perfectly.

Now after some years I switched to Macbook and I need to make the same thing on it. Could you recommend some options (visual studio or not)? I downloaded Visual Studio (C#) for Mac, which appears to be more complicated than it was on Win - designer in additional Xcode window, buttons need their functions to be assigned "by hand", ...

I heard programming on Mac is better, but the first impression looks otherwise. Now looking ahead - will I be able to use Interop.word to manipulate MS office files? Would be nice if the program would work on both Mac OS and Win. Possible?

I'm a hobby-programmer and this is the purpose why I ask - can you guys recommend the platform, methods, type of the app, settings, etc that this project will fit without starting with foul direction in the first place?

Comment: Found something related - https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this question is “in scope” for this site (it could be argued that any answer would be "opinion-based", but the short answer is that if you need Interop, on Mac at the moment the *only* simple way to do that is to use VBA. I do not even think there is *any* other way to use Interop on Mac at the moment.

But, although Mac Word VBA will *execute* VBA Userforms, the Mac Word VBA Editor does not let you *create or edit* Userform layouts or the underlying code. So you would have to create and maintain your code on the Windows platform. (You cannot even import Userforms (.frm/.frx) successfully on the Mac version so you cannot export/edit the VBA/re-import the code.)

Also, not everything available on Windows Word is available on Mac Word or is made available via the object model on Mac. For example, there are no ActiveX controls on Mac. However, it sounds to me as if VBA would do what you need.

To avoid using a VBA Userform, you could probably use a Word document containing standard legacy Word Form Fields to gather your data and perhaps a Word macrobutton to start code execution.

Technologically, there are now 3 alternatives to using Interop (forgetting about VSTO which ultimately uses the object model anyway and isn't available on Mac AFAIK)

1. Work directly with the .docx format
2. (Mac only) use Applescript
3. Use Microsoft's office-js web-based interface (basically with JavaScript/TypeScript at the moment)

(1) There are libraries that will let you do (1). Saying much more would be "opinion" but starting with VS+C# you *may* be able to use the standard Microsoft Open Office XML package if you use the right version of the .NET Framework.

(2) Applescript uses "Apple Events" to work with Word. It's a bit like using VBScript on Windows to control Word. The "object model" it uses is similar to the one VBA uses but has not really been maintained so many types of object in Word are not avaialble at all. Again, for what you propose it sounds as if Applescript would allow you to modify the document the way you need.

What neither (1) nor (2) give you is a *simple* facility to display a form to gather data. Applescript gives you a prompt facility. Beyond that, again it's a question of finding a suitable method and learning to work with it.

(3) office-js has the attraction of working on both Windows and Mac (and with the device/web-based versions of Word) *and* having a standard way to communicate with the user via a form (using an HTML-based form in a panel displayed in Word). However, it presents quite a different Word API from either VBA or Applescript and you would have to research that to determine whether or not you can do what you need with it. Visual Studio on Windows has some support for that, but the current version of VS on Mac doesn't have that.

Comment: @user3023137 even since posting that, the following has turned up - could be worth a look if you don't mind working with pre-release versions. Still doesn't solve the interop problem though. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/